# cart::remove not working i am using crinsane shopping cart library

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, shopping-cart

Here's my code:

**web.php**

```
Route::delete('/cart/{$product}', 'CartController@destroy')->name('cart.destroy');
```

**cart.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('cart.destroy',$item->rowId) }}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <button type="submit" class="cart-options">Remove</button>
</form>
```

**CartController.php**

```
public function destroy($id)
{
   Cart::remove($id);

   return back();
}
```

when I submit the form I am seeing a blank page with this:

> Sorry the page you are looking not found

Comment: In the future, format your post correctly. Secondly, where are you passing your CSRF token?

Comment: I pass it but still not working bro